# getting SCRIPT28: Out of stack space require-jquery.js, line 3792 character 3

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am creating a single page app proof of concept using requirejs (with jquery merged in) I am randomly getting Stack overflows in the app on different browsers. The error  is

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
require-jquery.js, line 3792 character 3

    acceptData: function( elem ) {
            // Do not set data on non-element because it will not be cleared (#8335).
    --->        if ( elem.nodeType && elem.nodeType !== 1 && elem.nodeType !== 9 ) {
                return false;
            }
```

Sometimes it occurs on loading the page, other times it occurs when I load modules, and yet other times it is when when I do hash changes. It's not consistent so I am wondering has anyone had issues with  requirejs doing this?

Comment: I have not. Most likely it is related to how you are using said scripts.

Comment: is it also intermittent in different browsers?

Comment: did some more testing I downloaded a standalone copey of require and jquery. Redid the script calls and redid the app.js and found its not requirejs but the jquery library. As for how its behaving, its intermittent on chrome safari and ie. I have not seen it in firebug on FF

Comment: found the issue it was the library I was using as a hashchange shim. I ripped it out went with another library and the stack overflows went away.

Comment: @jeffwerner I'm experiencing the same error at the same place.  Which shim library did you remove to solve it?